# Mails not going out from AWS SES

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Using c# and Amazon SES, we tried to send 1,000 emails on one shot. Out of 1,000, almost 250 emails are delivered. Remaining emails are not sent. What could be the problem for this? Whenever our sending emails limited to 200-300 emails are sent after that mails are not going why?

Comment: Are you in Sandbox or production mode? ( It is SES specific settings. The default is sandbox, you need to request it for every Region where you want to use SES.)

Comment: SES has [stats counters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html) as well as [delivery/bounce/complaint notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html).  Are you using these? What do they say, compared to your observations?

Comment: we are in production mode and using east Virginia. AWS ---- Adam Ocsvari

Answer (score 0):

SES has a sending limit of x emails/second.  You can have it raised, but considering the amount of emails you are attempting to send, it would be best to have your application stay within those limits.

Comment: 14 emails per second is our sending rate limit and 50k mails per day is the   sending limit.we used for loop to send emails   to recipients

Answer (score 0):

[SES Limits at AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html)